# Implement Control Panel hover style panel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How can I implement a control like windows 8 Control Panel with that hover effect, in c# ?

I know the links can be implemented with linklabel controls, but the container with that hover effect is a mistery to me.

Comment: You mean MouseEnter, highlight in blue, MouseLeave, return to white?

Comment: Yes, but what I really want to know is: is that a control that is available in .net/winforms ? Or do I have to implement it by myself ?